# The address of an array which is passed as a function's parameter IS NOT equal to the actual address

Tags: c, arrays

Specifically,here is my program on gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char ga[]="abc";
void func(char ca[])
{
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n",ca,&ca[0],&ca[1],++ca);
}
main()
{   
    func(ga);
    printf("%p %p %p\n",ga,&ga[0],&ga[1]);
}
```

And the output of it is

```
# ./a.out 
0x8049735 0x8049735 0x8049736 0x8049735
0x8049734 0x8049734 0x8049735
```

Then why the address of **ca** is **one** byte larger than the address of **ga**?

And why the value of **++ca** is equal to **ca**?

Comment: Undefined behaviour when one parameter is ++ca :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `++ca` to `ca` and you will get the expected results.
It is not necessary that in `printf("%p %p %p %p\n",ca,&ca[0],&ca[1],++ca);`, the arguments will be evaluated from left to right; such behaviour is compiler dependent.
In this case, they are being evaluated from right to left; first `ca` is being incremented and then the printing takes place.